# How can I have a scrollable body with fixed header and footer inside a container div? using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one container  with two children  elements inside of it. I want to place one child  at the top and other child  at the bottom of the container . The middle part (the content) should scroll between the top and bottom child  elements.

I want both children  elements inside the container  to have a fixed position and the content should scroll without scrolling both top and bottom div.

I'd like a solution using CSS or jQuery, please. For a JSFiddle example, see my comment below.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0xr2nwg2/9/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the below as a comment but because of low reputation I was unable to do it.

Take a look at the following jsfiddles:

1) http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/g2ydV/8/

2) http://jsfiddle.net/yASFU/

**Style:**

```
#content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help but you know you gave fix height to div 4000px. I can't do that cause I got dynamic data to display inside that div.

Comment: Thank you for answer but actually I got 5-6 div on the same page with horizontal scroll. If I make position:fixed then all header and footer moving along with scroll.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I succeed in what I suppose to do. All of your code help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another inner div to hold the content, and set `overflow-y: scroll` on it so that only the content will scroll and not the header and footer. Here is a modified version of your fiddle to illustrate this concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/vtuv6wh6/

Comment: Thanks all of you. I succeed in what I suppose to do. All of your code help me to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `position:fixed;` to the necessary elements in the CSS. So the CSS should look something like:

```
  .inside {
    top: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
   height:50px;
   position:fixed;

  }

  .inside2 {
    bottom: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
   height:50px;
   position:fixed;
  }
```

[Further read](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xr2nwg2/16/) to reflect the same.

Comment: Thank you for answer but actually I got 5-6 div on the same page with horizontal scroll. If I make position:fixed then all header and footer move along with scroll.

Comment: If you fix the position of the header and the footer, they won't move along with the scroll. And I don't know how horizontal scroll is also a problem, if you want the header and footer to be fixed and have a fixed width as well, then you can just add that.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I succeed in what I suppose to do. All of your code help me to achieve this.